# On array How can i select only column

Tags: php

I have an array like the one below in laravel which I want to fetch the column.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [table] => form_identification
            [column] => region
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [table] => form_identification
            [column] => province
        )

)
```

And I want the output like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [column] => region
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [column] => province
        )

)
```

Comment: Looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/352329).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider your first array as `$datas` variable here and we are using for each whole array

```php
foreach($datas as $data) {
    $result[] = array('column' => $data['column']);
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: `$result[]['column'] = $data['column'];`

Comment: Yes, @mickmackusa that's the alternate way too, Thanks.